# Setting up LDAP for Jupyter Server

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, authorization, jupyter

I have setup a Jupyter server using Anaconda, and currently, I'm running it using token authentication. I tried to follow steps mentioned in this link for setting up LDAP authorization for the server, but it doesn't show me the login page itself. https://github.com/jupyterhub/ldapauthenticator

Jupyter Version - 4.2.1

Can someone help me in setting up LDAP auth for Jupyter.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Midhun were you able to setup LDAP successfully in your environment?

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked for me.

First, I installed the jupyterhub LDAP authenticator.

```
pip3 install jupyterhub-ldapauthenticator
```

After the installation, I edited the config file.

```
nano /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
```

The config looks like this:

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'ldapauthenticator.LDAPAuthenticator'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.server_hosts =  ['ldap://ldap.example.com:389']
c.LDAPAuthenticator.bind_user_dn = 'uid=ldapbind,cn=users,dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com‘
c.LDAPAuthenticator.bind_user_password = ‘Password’
c.LDAPAuthenticator.user_search_base = 'cn=users,dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com‘
c.LDAPAuthenticator.user_search_filter = '(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid={username}))'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.username_pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9_.][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,252}[a-zA-Z0-9_.$-]?'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.create_user_home_dir = True
c.LDAPAuthenticator.create_user_home_dir_cmd = ['mkhomedir_helper']
```

In the next step, I installed the following LDAP packages.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap libpam-ldap nscd
```

While the installation you can make the required changes for the configuration. After the installation, I needed to reconfigure the package because I need to change the password encryption.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config
```

Next, I changed the config file ldap.conf.

```
nano /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
```

From:

```
#BASE    dc=unixmen,dc=local
#URI     ldap://192.168.1.100
```

To:

```
BASE    dc=ldap,dc=example,dc=com
URI     ldap://ldap.example.com
```

The second config file I edited is nsswitch.conf. The ldap need to be added four times.

```
passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
netgroup:       ldap
```

After the changes, the service needs to be restarted.

```
systemctl restart nscd
```

Comment: I am setting up ldap authentication with AD integration. Is it mandatory to make changes in `ldap.conf` file? I didn't see anything related to this in jupyterhub github page. Can you please share any other reference if you have?

Comment: Hi were you able to try the above example. Is it working ?